# How to extends class for taking methods from other two classes

Tags: java, inheritance

I have the following classes:

```
class Vehicle {
    public void Move() {
        System.out.println("Move");
    }
}

class Bike extends Vehicle {
    public void RideOnBackWheel() {}
}

class VehicleWithEngine extends Vehicle {
    public void EngineStart() {}
    public void EngineStop() {}
}
```

Now, I have to create class Motorbike with the methods from Bike and VehicleWithEngine, but it doesn't works:

```
class Motorbike extends Bike, VehicleWithEngine {
    private boolean engine = false;

    @Override
    public void EngineStart() {
        engine = true;
        System.out.println("Engine started.");
    }

    @Override
    public void EngineStop() {
        engine = false;
        System.out.println("Engine stopped.");
    }

    @Override
    public void RideOnBackWheel() {
        if(engine) System.out.println("1 wheel");
    }

    @Override
    public void Move() {
        if(engine) System.out.println("Motorbike.move()");
    }
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You can extend only one `Class` in Java and implement multiple `Interfaces` http://csis.pace.edu/~bergin/patterns/multipleinheritance.html

Comment: Method names should begin with lowercase, by convention.

Comment: you could make a Motorbike class that uses composition, whereby the class contains a Bike and VehicleWithEngine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In java you can't inherit from two classes. You must change your `Vehicle`, `Bike` and `VehicleWithEngine` classes to interfaces using `implements` keyword instead od `extends` in Motorbike class.

```
interface Vehicle
{
    default public void Move()
    {
        System.out.println("Move");
    }
}

interface Bike extends Vehicle
{
    public void RideOnBackWheel();
}

interface VehicleWithEngine extends Vehicle
{
    public void EngineStart();
    public void EngineStop();
}

class Motorbike implements Bike, VehicleWithEngine
{
    private boolean engine = false;

    @Override
    public void EngineStart()
    {
        engine = true;
        System.out.println("Engine started.");
    }

    @Override
    public void EngineStop()
    {
        engine = false;
        System.out.println("Engine stopped.");
    }

    @Override
    public void RideOnBackWheel()
    {
        if(engine) { System.out.println("1 wheel"); }
    }

    @Override
    public void Move()
    {
        if(engine) { System.out.println("Motorbike.move()"); }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `Bike` and `VehicleWithEngine` don't actually have implementations. If so, you can turn them into interfaces and have `Motorbike` implement both:

```
interface Bike extends Vehicle {
    void RideOnBackWheel();
}

interface VehicleWithEngine extends Vehicle {
    void EngineStart();
    void EngineStop();
}

class Motorbike implements Bike, VehicleWithEngine {
    // implementations
}
```

If `Bike` and `Vehicle` have stateless implementations (they don't need to directly access member variables), you can turn them into [default methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html), for example:

```
interface Bike extends Vehicle {
    default void RideOnBackWheel() {
        // implementation
    }
}
```

Otherwise it's not possible to extend from two classes. See the linked duplicate.